# Can't get my app script to run using my gmail account

Tags: authentication, google-calendar-api

I am new to Google app script and created a simple script to read my calendar events.

When I try running it, I get the Auth window where I select my gmail account and then I get the attached error message right away.

Error Message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Are you executing it in Google Apps Script itself or from somewhere else? Is the account that is executing it the one that created the script?

Comment: Thanks Marti. I am executing it from within Google Apps Script. And yes, I am running it using my gmail account and that's the one I am logged in to create the script. I wonder if this has to do with me running this outside of a GSuite account... I am running this using my @gmail.com account.

Comment: When using a Gmail account it shows me a warning but allows me to continue behind a small link on the bottom left for advanced options. If you make a new project that only does `Logger.log('Hello, World!')`, does this behavior persist? Also, could you tell me your browser?